# How to improve elasticsearch result by using data store in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, elasticsearch, search

I use both elasticsearch and mongodc to store a part of data.
Now I'll need both of then to optimize the search result .
So I wonder how to modify my query clause.

For example,I store the info of product in elasticsearch server so I can query and find all product match the name "Iphone". And I store the search behavior in mongo db as I can know which model people search the most ,etc.

And now I would like to improve my elasticsearch result by adding data stored in mongo db.Do any one know how to solve this in simple way? Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your friendly reminder.
I’m new here.